# Warning occurred on while build the flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, error-handling, flutter-dependencies

I added some dependencies on my flutter app but there was an error when building the app. The app was run. Please, anyone can tell me the correct reason?

**Dependencies,**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0
  firebase_database: ^6.0.0
  #cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0

  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.6
  google_maps_place_picker: ^1.0.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  multi_image_picker: ^4.7.14
  transparent_image: ^2.0.0
```

**Warning,**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: C:\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.20.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-7.0.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) {
                                                ^
1 warning
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have application.java replace with the following:

```
  @Override
public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
}
```